# SharePoint 2013 with integrated SP 1 - Installing Language Pack SP1

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, language, language-pack

What is the "best practice" way to install a Language Pack at new SharePoint 2013 Server with integrated SP 1?

My idea:

1. Install SharePoint 2013 with integrated SP 1
2. PSConfig
3. Install Language Pack
4. PSConfig
5. Install Language Pack SP1
6. PSConfig

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple views and ways to do, But i would recommend the way we adopt all the time.

This process is for all the server in the farm( you can do parallel)

- Install SharePoint 2013 with SP1
- Install the Langugae Packs
- Install the Services Packs for LPs

Ps Config the single thread process, Now you need to run the PSconfig on 1st server which will host Central Admin and then rest of the servers (if any).

- Run the PS Config on 1st server(which host Central Admin)